# Set Correct Encoding Type When Posting Form

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to make a post using HttpClient.  This is what I have tried:

```
    public static async void DoPost(string url, string user, string password)
    {

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("method", "login"));
        postValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user", user));
        postValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pass", password));

        FormUrlEncodedContent formEnc = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postValues);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, formEnc))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            // ... Read the string.
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // ... Display the result.
            if (result != null &&
            result.Length >= 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "...");
            }
        }
    }
```

It throws an exception for not having the right encoding type.  I am not sure what the encoding type should be or where to set it.  This is the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadBufferedContentAsString()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<>c.<ReadAsStringAsync>b__36_0(HttpContent s)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<WaitAndReturnAsync>d__62`2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at SuiteCrmTest.Program.<DoPost>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\SuiteCrmTest\src\SuiteCrmTest\Program.cs:line 34
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2147024809
       Message='"ISO-8859-1"' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
Parameter name: name
       ParamName=name
       Source=System.Private.CoreLib
       StackTrace:
            at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
            at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
            at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(String name)
            at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadBufferedContentAsString()
       InnerException:
```

How do I set correct content type?

edit:

received headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 23:46:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip



HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 23:46:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
```

The first header is whats causing the issues I think.  The second header I think is a redirect to a html message.  On the first header there is an encoded message in `ISO-8859-1` which I guess is the reason it is throwing error but I don't know how to read that.  How do I set the charset?

Comment: change `public static async void` to `public static async Task` and see if the error stops. You should avoid using `async void`

Comment: @Nkosi This does not alter the exception. It still doesn't like the encoding type

Comment: Scan the request being sent and confirm the `ContentType` header. based on error message `"ISO-8859-1"' is not a supported encoding name` you seem to be using an unsupported encoding

Comment: @Nkosi The return content type in the debugger shows `Headers = {Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"
}`

Comment: @Nkosi in fiddler it shows the incoming response content type as `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Post a snippet of the request and response headers.

Comment: @Nkosi updated my question

Comment: Something doesn't add up. you are sending `FormUrlEncodedContent` request but your snippet has `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. content type should be `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @Nkosi Sorry, it seems fiddler isn't picking up the sent request from visual studio, only from postman. Both these headers were from the api.  I can't seem to get fiddler to hear the request from VS2015

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120376/discussion-between-guerrilla-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 0):

The API I was accessing allows a field to specify the return type.  I specified Json in the form field and then it worked.